# How to check if a column is nullable or not if it has primary key constraint in Informix

Tags: informix

In the link below, the significance of Bit Value is given as

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.sqlr.doc/sqlrmst41.htm

```
Bit Value       Significance When Bit Is Set
0x0100          NULL values are not allowed
```

But in case if the column has primary key constraint, then this bit not getting set. Why?

The problem occurs in informix v 11.0 but not in > =1.7 versions

Answer (score 2):

I see the bit being set with Informix 11.70.FC6 on Mac OS X 10.9.4.

```
CREATE TABLE explicit_notnull(pk INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE implicit_notnull(pk INTEGER PRIMARY KEY);
SELECT t.tabid, t.tabname, C.colno, C.colname, C.coltype, C.collength
  FROM SysTables AS t
  JOIN SysColumns AS C ON t.tabid = C.tabid
 WHERE t.tabname IN ('explicit_notnull', 'implicit_notnull');
```

Output:

```
133 explicit_notnull    1   pk  258 4
134 implicit_notnull    1   pk  258 4
```

The NOT NULL bit is set in both tables.

Please specify which version of Informix you are using and on which platform you are using it.  And test the script above, and provide your counter-example.

Comment: Yep 11.7 seems to be working fine. I tested it in 11.0 (Windows) and it doesn't work. May be this issue is fixed in version >= 11.7. Below is the output which i see in 11.0. ----

1642, "implicit_notnull", 1, "pk", 2, 4

Comment: I wasn't aware that it had ever been broken (I would have expected the behaviour I demonstrated in any version of Informix), but it is not impossible for there to have been a bug in 11.10 (and once it's there, who knows whether it is in 11.50, or 10.00, or ...).  I no longer have access to archaic versions of Informix so I can't check for you.